# How to install boost modules in boost 1.57 (application and dll)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I want to install:

- https://github.com/retf/Boost.Application
- https://github.com/apolukhin/Boost.DLL

I'm following instruction from Boost.DLL which says:

- clone `Boost.DLL` repository: `git clone https://github.com/apolukhin/Boost.DLL dll`
- enter the `dll/test` folder and run `./b2`: `cd dll/test; ../../../b2`

tests fails with:

> F:\P\thridparty\boost\boost/function/function_template.hpp(767) :
>   error C2664: 'int (boost::detail::function::function_buffer &,T0)' :
>   cannot conv parameter 2 from 'std::string' to
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> '

(I also was trying to copy include/boost/* into /boost/*)

As far as I can see the tests passed...

But when I'm trying to use it I can't find it... Even with cmake

```
find_package( Boost 1.57 COMPONENTS system filesystem dll application REQUIRED )
```

I'm getting:

> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>       boost_dll
>       boost_application
> ```

So what is proper way of installing this modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost::Application and Boost::DLL are not part of the Boost, so they can not be found by Cmake.

I'm not digging into Boost::DLL so far, but Boost::Application can be used by simple clone/submodule with your project. It is header only library, so no build/install required.

Example project can be found [on github](https://github.com/snikulov/boost.app.cmake).

In my case it is git submodule to < project root >/hdr/application.

Comment: It seems like great example for me, thank you! I will try it right now.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

- If you want to use an existing boost installation, then, thanks to the libraries being header only, you just need to copy the contents of the directory "include/boost" to the include folder of your boost installation, eg.

> copy "Boost.Application/include/boost/*" to "boost_installation_dir/boost/"

- If you want to build boost and run tests etc, you need to copy them into the libs directory of your boost sources (not your boost installation), so there is a boost/libs/application and a "boost/libs/dll", eg:

> copy "application" to "boost_src_dir/libs"

Then you build and install boost just as you normally do on your platform (follow the [getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/index.html))

Either way: You do not have to do find_package in your cmake file as these two libs are header only, it work just by include the headers in your source file.

As for the tests: They don't work for me either, but you don't actually need them for using the libs..